# Securely publish tableau workbook to multiple clients

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a Tableau server with multiple websites, one per client.

I need to automate the process of publishing reports to each client individually but ensure that each client can only access their own data.
Due to the complexity of each workbook, the data sources cannot be live connections, they must be extracts. (even if blank ones, where I can refresh once the connections are updated to each client).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the workbook design identical in each case, where only the data changes?

Comment: Have you considered publishing the same dashboard file which uses row-level security and filters the data for your respective clients from the same data source? If your access is already defined in Tableau Server, then all your clients will visit the same workbook but can only view their respective data.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore yes, they're identical, the only difference is that each client have their own DB server and different connections

Comment: @Debayan Each client have their own website on the server. And their data live in different DB servers, and each one with its own connection details.

Comment: This API could help. https://github.com/tableau/document-api-python